# Как создать Membership Provider с полями пользователя не предусмотренными базовой реализацией?

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net, авторизация

Здравствуйте. Работодатель дал тестовое задание, в задании, среди прочего, нужно сделать membership provider, который берет данные о пользователях из xml файла. Дело в том, что обойтись полями, дефолтными от базового мембершипа, не выйдет. Нужно внедрить как минимум тип пользователя worker или hirer. Возможно это нужно сделать ролями? Как это можно сделать самым простым и красивым способом?   Кидайте ссылки с примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: Да. Для полного управления всеми аспектами пользователей, нужно наследовать три класса. MembershipProvider, RoleProvider, ProfileProvider. Создаем свои версии этих классов, и управляем аутентификацией, ролями и данными пользователей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ использовать мембершип профайл.